# three-way contigency table gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary

```
library(gtsummary)
one <- mtcars %>% filter(am==0) %>% select(cyl,disp,hp,wt,vs) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by=cyl) %>% add_p
two <- mtcars %>% filter(am==1)%>% select(cyl,disp,hp,wt,vs) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by=cyl) %>% add_p
three <- mtcars %>% select(disp,hp,wt,vs,am) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by=am) %>% add_p
tbl_merge(list(one,two,three))
```

Is there an easy way of removing all columns under table 3, retaining only the p-value column as a test for the difference between tables 1 and 2? Or is there another way of doing 3-way contingency tables in gtsummary?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the `tbl_strata()` function. http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_strata.html

```r
library(gtsummary)

trial %>%
  select(age, grade, stage, trt) %>%
  mutate(grade = paste("Grade", grade)) %>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata = grade,
    .tbl_fun =
      ~ .x %>%
      tbl_cross(stage, trt, margin = NULL) 
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks-but not quite what I had in mind since I´d like to have p-values within each strata, but also between stratas. See output from my example - but I´d prefer to just retain the p-value column from the column comparing the other two stratas.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your example! You can switch the `tbl_cross()` to `tbl_summary()` and add `add_p()` after the `tbl_summary()`. That can get you stratified tables by `"am"`. you'll need to merge the last overall table still: there is no single function to handle this all at once.

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg 
Hi Daniel,  I was wondering if it was possible to to change the output to percentages instead of count and to maybe transpose the table so the strata are in a column to the left of the table , the way it they should be in APA tables.